# Symfony2 dynamic form

Tags: forms, symfony

I'd like to create a specific form using cities to draw a path.

Let's say I'm a driver, I wanna make some carpooling, I want to add a new path : I'm going from NY to San Francisco. All I have to do is select NY as departure, and SF as arrival (I got a City entity, I'm using select2 to make my choice)

Now, the tricky part: Once I've selected my departure and arrival, I'd like to add a "add stopover" button that would allow me to add stopovers if needed (Let's say, I want to make a detour by Las Vegas)

Is it possible to create such a form with Symfony2, so that I can add any number of stopovers ?

Comment: is this what you are  looking for ?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible with Symfony. You can add a list in a form and make the items editable, delete-able and you can also let the user add a new item to the list.
The [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) that Wonde gave you gives you all the information.